# mailto: in URLs without a mail client installed

Tags: c++, winapi, email, mailto

I ran into an issue. I display an email link in my UI. When the user clicks that link it is opened as such:

```
LPCTSTR url=L"mailto:myemail@gmail.com?subject=my_subject";
ShellExecute(hParentWnd, _T("open"), url, NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

This works for as long as the end-user has an email client installed. But what happens if the email client is not installer is that command simply opens the home page in the default web browser.

Any idea how to address this?

Comment: What sort of behaviour would you like to happen instead?

Comment: @JohnSibly: Give me an error, so that I can use some other means to display it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can determine what executable/command handles the `mailto:` protocol with [`AssocQueryString("mailto")`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773471%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (or by looking in `hkcr\mailto\shell\open\command`).

If your lucky this will be empty for a machine with no association set.

Comment: Here's how to do it: `TCHAR buff[1024]; DWORD size = 1024; BOOL bOK = SUCCEEDED(AssocQueryString(0, ASSOCSTR_EXECUTABLE, L"mailto", NULL, buff, &size));`

Comment: @c00000fd: This above "mailto" code doesn't run in win10 x64. AssocQUeryString always return false but if we check "http" then it returns true and also prints location of exec path like
 
HRESULT hr = AssocQueryString(ASSOCF_NOTRUNCATE|ASSOCF_REMAPRUNDLL|ASSOCF_NOFIXUPS,ASSOCSTR_EXECUTABLE,L"http",NULL,buff,&size);